# Unity3D Color mulitple child gameobject with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project i want multiple child gameobjects colored with red.
In serveral forums i found the solution to do this with c#, but unfortunately i could not found a solution which works for me.

All of my child objects has the tag 'colorChild'.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ColorChildObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GamObject PartentColor;
    public GameObject[] coloredChilds;
    public Material red;

    void Start()
    {
        if(coloredChilds == null)
           // coloredChilds = ParentColor.transform.FindChild("ChildName")
           // coloredChilds = ParentColor.transform.FindChild("colorChild")

           // coloredChilds = GameObject.FindGameObjectswithTag("colorChild")
           // coloredChilds = ParentColor.FindGameObjectswithTag("colorChild") 

        foreach (GameObject colorChild in colorChilds)
        {
            colorChild.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = red;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately none of those four (comments) had worked for me. I hope someone can show me how i can do that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: it sounds likely that at the time this code runs the children havent been made yet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

```
if(coloredChilds == null)
```

will **never** be `true` here!

The

```
public GameObject[] coloredChilds;
```

is a **serialized field** since it is `public` and thus gets **automatically initialized by the Unity Inspector** as empty array and stored in your scene file!

---

Either make it `private` so it isn't serialized anymore

```
private GameObject[] coloredChilds;
```

or change your check for e.g. the length like

```
if(coloredChilds.Length == 0)
    ...
```

the first is definitely more secure since you might add objects to the array via the Inspector that don't even have a `Renderer` component and end up with exceptions ;)

---

Then the first two wouldn't even compile

```
coloredChilds = ParentColor.transform.FindChild("ChildName");
coloredChilds = ParentColor.transform.FindChild("colorChild");
```

since `FindChild` returns a single reference and you want to assign it to an array. (I don't know which Unity version you use but it was also removed and you should probably rather use `transform.Find` anyway).

The second depends on what you want

```
coloredChilds = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("colorChild");
```

would search for these childs in the entire scene!

```
coloredChilds = ParentColor.FindGameObjectswWthTag("colorChild");
```

only under the `ParentColor`.

Both only return **active** GameObjects! And in both cases the `W` should be capital.

---

Now actually I wouldn't use any of the solutions you apparently found but rather use [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html) and simply do something like

```
// returns all Renderer references of any children (also nested) of ParentColor
// including the Renderer of ParentColor itself if exists
// by passing true this also returns inactive/disabled Renderers
Renderer[] coloredChildren = ParentColor.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);

foreach(var child in coloredChildren)
{ 
    child.material = red; 
}
```

directly without going by the name of objects.

If needed you can then still further filter the childs e.g. use only the ones that have `ParentColor` as parent -> only first level childs get colored

```
foreach(var child in coloredChilds)
{
    if(child.transform.parent != ParentColor.transform) continue;

    child.material = red;
}
```

or go by tag you already assigned

```
foreach(var child in coloredChilds)
{
    if(!child.CompareTag("colorChild")) continue;

    child.material = red;
}
```

Comment: Awesome .. Thanks a lot. I tried the `GetComponentsinChildren` and it worked the first time .. you are awesome

Comment: Not only will it never be true, the program would vomit errors if it did!